# Customizing Euler Diagram colors with eulerr R

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram, eulerr

I'm trying to plot an Euler Diagram using the eulerr package by Johan Larsson in R. I'm following [this example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/index.html) where the developer explains how to customize colors/border transparency. However, when I try to implement it with the following code:

```
fit2 <- euler(c(A = 16971, B = 218, C = 215, 
                "A&B" = 112, "A&C" = 112, "B&C"= 51,"A&B&C" = 23))
plot(fit2,
 polygon_args = list(col = c("dodgerblue4", "darkgoldenrod1", "cornsilk4"),
                     border = "transparent"),
 text_args = list(font = 8), counts=TRUE)
```

Colors/border remain unchanged.

I am using  RStudio 1.0.136, R 3.3.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry about this. That post is old and the arguments have changed.

Try this instead

```
fit2 <- euler(c(A = 16971, B = 218, C = 215, 
                "A&B" = 112, "A&C" = 112, "B&C"= 51,"A&B&C" = 23))
plot(fit2,
     fills = c("dodgerblue4", "darkgoldenrod1", "cornsilk4"),
     edges = FALSE,
     fontsize = 8,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 8))
```

[image]