# Unable to change colors in eulerr

Tags: r, venn-diagram, eulerr

I have three lists of genes for which I am attempting to plot the euler plots using eulerr in R. I'm having trouble figuring out why the code [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044564/customizing-euler-diagram-colors-with-eulerr-r) isn't allowing me to change the colors of the different sets.

Here is a sample code:

```
d <- list(a = c(1:10),
          b = c(2:31),
          c = c(8:14))
d <- lapply(d, as.character)

fit <- plot(euler(d),quantities = TRUE)
plot(fit,
     fills = c("pink", "darkgoldenrod1", "black"),
     edges = FALSE,
     fontsize = 8,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 8))
```

Here is the output image:

[image]

Colors displayed are the default ones rather than the ones specified by me.

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Comment: you are calling `plot.euler()` on an object from `plot.euler()`, which is only causing the plot from the first call to be drawn on the current device.

Comment: AH! I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
library(eulerr)
d <- list(a = c(1:10),
          b = c(2:31),
          c = c(8:14))
d <- lapply(d, as.character)

fit <- plot(euler(d),
            fills = c("pink", "darkgoldenrod1", "black"),
            quantities = TRUE)
fit
```

[image]